# Filtering in a nested field

Tags: elasticsearch

My document samples are as below:

```
[
  {
    "paperType": "a4",
    "paperName": "copierbond",
    "details": [
      {
        "fieldName": "paperColor",
        "text": "red"
      },
      {
        "fieldName": "paperThickness",
        "double": 90.0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "paperType": "a4",
    "paperName": "copierbond",
    "details": [
      {
        "fieldName": "paperColor",
        "text": "red"
      },
      {
        "fieldName": "paperThickness",
        "double": 89.9
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "paperType": "a4",
    "paperName": "bestcopierbond",
    "details": [
      {
        "fieldName": "paperColor",
        "text": "white"
      },
      {
        "fieldName": "paperThickness",
        "double": 90.2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "paperType": "a4",
    "paperName": "bestcopierbond",
    "details": [
      {
        "fieldName": "paperColor",
        "text": "white"
      },
      {
        "fieldName": "paperThickness",
        "double": 90.1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My mapping is as below:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "details": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "fieldName": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "textVal": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "doubleVal": {
            "type": "double"
          }
        },
        "paperName": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "paperType": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to retrieve the documents such that the `details` field contains only some pairs such as `fieldName-text`, and does not contain `fieldName-double`. An example response:

```
[
  {
    "paperType": "a4",
    "paperName": "copierbond",
    "details": [
      {
        "fieldName": "paperColor",
        "text": "red"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "paperType": "a4",
    "paperName": "copierbond",
    "details": [
      {
        "fieldName": "paperColor",
        "text": "red"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "paperType": "a4",
    "paperName": "bestcopierbond",
    "details": [
      {
        "fieldName": "paperColor",
        "textVal": "white"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "paperType": "a4",
    "paperName": "bestcopierbond",
    "details": [
      {
        "fieldName": "paperColor",
        "text": "white"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I checked the documentation of nested fields but could not find a way to omit specific fields in queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [exclude](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html#source-filtering).

```
GET index/_search
{
  "_source": {
    "excludes": "details.doubleVal"
  }, 
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: This would remove other objects that contain `doubleVal` key with desired `fieldName`. Is there a way to combine or specifically point out field pairs to be included?

Comment: Does not possible. In this scenario, your application handles the return response.